# Taking Microsoft Access Queries and Putting them Together in One Result

Tags: ms-access

This seems like it would be super easy, but I have yet to find anything remotely helpful. I'm doing count queries in MS Access of multiple things in the table.

Example:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM DataBase
WHERE "X" <> "Y"
```

I have multiple queries of this type, and I want to put them in one result. The update doesn't seem to support a function of queries or I just unable to figure it out.

*Edit:
My Problem isn't combining the results into one query. The problem is that I want to take a count of the results, and then take that count and put it in a database.

I am counting different things from a single data base. I have a count of how many things are X, how many things are Y. After I have all those counts, I want to put them together in a different table as one result.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what do you mean by putting them in one result (a `UNION`?)

Comment: Yes, it's confusing.  Maybe you want to sum all the results.

Comment: My Problem isn't combining the results into one query.  The problem is that I want to take a count of the results, and then take that count and put it a database.  So I am counting different things from a single data base.  I have a count of how many things are X, how many things are Y.  After I have all those counts, I want to put them together in a different table as one result.

Comment: Can you write up an example of some tables' data you want summarized and what the answer would look like?

Comment: -1 for unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a UNION query:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208962(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: The user doesn't want to stack query results; the user wants to accumulate totals from various queries.  At least, I think so, though communication seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a query something like this for each contributing source:

```
UPDATE tblTotal
SET Total = [Total]+
    (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM tblContributer
        WHERE "X" <> "Y") AS Contributer;
```

You will need to build up to this solution.  Start with something like:

```
UPDATE tblTotal
SET Total = [Total]+1;
```

Comment: This is in the direction I am trying to go, what exactly do you mean by "build up" to this solution.  I know the code you posted works in regular SQL but I keep getting a syntax error with Access.  It doesn't like the SET equaling a query I think.

If I try your second line of code, it asks me to enter the value of Total.  Is that the desired effect?

Comment: `Total` would be a field name.  You must replace that with your actual field name.

Comment: How do you know 'the code [I] posted works in regular SQL'?  What regular SQL are you talking about?  How do you know it works?

Comment: I've wrote brief SQL within a language, and what I mean is I know you can have SQL statements within SQL statements like that if using C# or something like that.  I don't know if Access is any different.

UPDATE Out
SET Coxes = 0 + (SELECT Count(*)
FROM Master
WHERE Rank ="CXN")
WHERE Summer = 2013;


This gives me a "Operation must use an updateable query"

Comment: So, try:  `UPDATE Out SET Coxes = 1 WHERE Summer = 2013;`  Fix the "updateable" issue.   Then work on querying `Master`.

Comment: It works if I set it to a static value, I don't know if it's even possible for Microsoft Access to have an update query where you set it to a Count query.  Do you know if it is?